# How does one differientiate wrapped layers in the command pattern that are logically named the same?

Tags: c#, architecture, command-pattern

I have this interface...

```
public interface ICheckThatDocumentExistsCommand
{
   bool Execute( string userId, string docId );
}
```

In the implementation, I only want to validate the two id's and, if valid, to return the result of another interface...

```
public interface ICheckThatDocumentExistsCommand
{
   bool Execute( UserId userId, DocumentId docId );
}
```

I want to define the interfaces in the same business domain assembly, but I'm having difficulty deciding how to differentiate the two (or more) layers. Logically, I perceive they are similar if not identical in name, so I can't put them under the same namespace. Do I separate via namespace? A "Validation" namespace and a "Something-else" namespace? Or do I expand the already wordy name into something a bit ridiculous like...

```
public interface IValidateIdsAndThenCheckThatDocumentExistsCommand
```

I am seeing this come up more and more as I keep functions small and single-purposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an uncommon problem using the command pattern.  I can usually keep Command names to four or five words at most, but occasionally something longer is needed.

I see headaches for two interfaces with the same name:

1. Any class that references both assemblies will have to use fully qualified class name.
2. Source control headaches around keeping the files straight in your head (which one am I merging right now?), assuming your file names match your class names.
3. GoTo Type in Resharper will always require an extra step.

I agree that the extra work done by the first interface should be reflected in the name.  Your suggestion would work, but you could shorten it to something like

```
IValidateIdsAndCheckForDocumentCommand
```

That's not too long.  :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing my head and reminding me that the extra work deserves recognition. For this simple situation, I think I'll take the name you suggested. Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 2):

Well, its the implementing class that is figuring out what to do with the params....so why not let the implementing class determine and validate the types....

```
public interface ICheckThatDocumentExistsCommand
{
  bool Execute<t1,t2>(t1 userID, t2 docId);
}
```

Comment: Quote an interesting solution and one that I will keep with me +1. However, now that I think about it, that the types differ at all can be mere coincidence. In another situation, the signatures may be the same. This pushes me further toward a naming solution.

Answer (score 1):

I like Tims answer because it's smart, and I like Thomas's answer because he obviously know the territory.

If it were me, I'd most likely use different namespaces.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like a namespace solution because this provides a home for different custom return types, parameter types, supporting interfaces, etc. I'll definitely be using this, so +1. However, for a very small problem domain, I think the simplest thing is a modest name change.